# Problem with UIImageView when resizing UIView

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimageview, autoresize

This is the problem that I have:

I have an UIImageView inside an UIView.

Then I rotate the UIImageView 45 degrees using gestureRecognizers with 2 fingers.

Everything seem good now but when I start resize the UIView about -10px width, height by changing the UIView's frame, the UIImageView become very ugly, it does not resize with ratio.
It become stretch.

It does not happen when I rotate the image with 90 or 180 or 270 degrees. the UIImage resize OK.

Sorry for my bad English.

Tung Do

Answer (score 2):

Redraw the image after the pinch.

Comment: Can you explain a little more Terente. How can I redraw an UIImageView ?

Comment: Just remove it from the super view and read it. Or subclass uiimageview and make an method that calls drawRect.